# NavLink/Link from React-router-dom not working (blank screen)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi guys I was starting out on React and came across this problem, this is my Navbar component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

    const Navbar = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <NavLink as={NavLink} exact to="/">
            Hello
          </NavLink>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default Navbar;
```

and this is my App.js:

```
    import "./App.css";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
    
    const App = () => {
      return <Navbar />;
    };

    export default App;
```

when I run the code this is what happens:

[React App running on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0im5.png)

Also the link is not clickable nor has an underline like when using a simple  tag
And what's even worse is that if I change the import statement in my Navbar.js from:

```
import { BrowserRouter as NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
```

everything goes blank:

[React app running on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTszH.png)

my react-router-dom version is "^6.3.0"

please help I have seen different articles and I couldn't come up with a solution

Comment: Routers and links are not the same thing. Routers render routes, links link to them. Your code appears to be missing the router and routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following day the issue arose again and I was greeted with the blank page yet again.

Here is what I did to get it working for good this time.

after a lot of researching articles and trial and error, I found a simple solution. And I think this will help others as well.

I just changed the import statement in my app.js from:

```
import { Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

This fixed the issue of the blank screen.

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import About from "./components/pages/About";
import Contact from "./components/pages/Contact";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

also for the  texts from other components to appear
I used *element*:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

instead of *component*:

```
<Route path="/" component={<Home />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain to you a bit how react-router works. There are 2 components you need: the router that will show the component you want, depending on the path you have, and the navbar, which will change that path.

Let's start with the router component, BrowserRouter. This is an example from docs. In here, you define what components the router to show on your page, depending on the path:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Now, you need a way to navigate to these routes. For that, you can use Link (should work with NavLink as well):

```
  <nav>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/teams">Teams</Link>
  </nav>
```

Basically, your mistake is that you either have one or the other, not both at the same time. You need both to work.

Comment: Oh yes I do understand those. but the problem is the fact that it is not rendering anything on the browser

Comment: Not rendering anything means the router has no route defined for the path you have. For example, to render something on /teams path, you need to have a <Route> defined, like in my example. Also, make sure that the router code is rendered at all (i e. Write it in <App> component). If you still struggle, I can provide you a fully working demo.

Answer (score 0):

in v6+ keywords "exact" and "strict" don't work anymore on NavLink, instead put "end"

you don't use BrowserRouter as a navlink but

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom
<Router>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
       <Route path="/page1" element={<PageOne />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

or

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
<NavLink className={({ isActive }) => "nav-link" + (isActive ? " activated" : "")} end to="/home">
    home
</NavLink>
```

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: I tried that but still nothing renders.

Comment: i edited the code, i hope it helps @BemenetS.Bekele

Comment: I copied and pasted the code but I still get the blank screen. But it was something I didn't try and I appreciate the help.

Comment: if you copy-paste it will not work, i was giving an example

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I have found a solution to my problem.

I simply updated node and npm to the latest version and that seemed to resolve the blank screen issue.

for npm I just typed in the command:

```
npm update -g
```

Next I downloaded and installed the LTS version of node.js from:

```
https://nodejs.org/en/
```

I thank everyone for their contribution. Bye

Comment: Or at least for now this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

For others having this issue the real fix is that your NavBar component should be nested within your BrowserRouter like so :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import About from "./components/pages/About";
import Contact from "./components/pages/Contact";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar /> {/* Nested in Router */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**import React from "react";**
Add the above line to your file Navbar component then this issue resolved

Comment: As of React version 17, it is no longer necessary to `import React from 'react'`. More info [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html). So that cannot be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me, by observing my issue, the solution was to put Navbar inside . If Navbar is outside Browser router, that causes blank page without any warning about the problem.

This is the right solution:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

This is the bad using of Navbar and BrowserRouter:

```
<div>
<Navbar />
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```